# Check if matching record exists in joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `categories` and `prodvscats`

```
categories              prodvscats

  id            |       id      
  title         |       categories_id
```

each table has some rows for example:

```
categories              prodvscats

  categ1            |       categ1      
  categ2            |       categ2
  categ3
  categ4
```

I would like to return all categories but I want to know which of them are existing in the `prodvscats` table.

Desired result:

```
  title                boolean variable exists
  categ1            |       1      
  categ2            |       1
  categ3            |       0
  categ4            |       0
```

I tried with `join` but it returns only the first two rows. Maybe it needs something like case but I don't know how to do.

```
SELECT categories.id, categories.title
FROM categories
        INNER JOIN prodvscats ON prodvscats.categories_id = categories.id
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to join the two tables. This will return all rows including those where category does not exist in the other table. Then use `GROUP BY` to consolidate categories and `COUNT` to determine if match(es) exist:

```
SELECT
    categories.id,
    categories.title,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(prodvscats.id) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS product_exists
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN prodvscats ON categories.id = prodvscats.categories_id 
GROUP BY categories.id, categories.title
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
SELECT categories.id, categories.title, 
IF(prodvscats.categories_id IS NULL, '0', '1') AS exists_value
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN prodvscats ON prodvscats.categories_id = categories.id
ORDER BY id
```